# yarn command exit code 0 - electron

Tags: node.js, electron, yarnpkg

Some of my friends are sharing some demo projects, so that I can learn `electron`, I know react already, I think.

So before editing source, I'm trying to build and see how it is.

In package json there are some instruction :

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node scripts/remix-dl.js",
    "dev": "node scripts/start.js",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --color --config=webpack.config.js --env=production",
    "pack": "yarn dist:all --dir",
    "dist": "yarn build && electron-builder",
    "dist:all": "yarn dist -wml",
    "dist:windows": "yarn dist -w",
    "dist:mac": "yarn dist -m",
    "dist:linux": "yarn dist -l"
  },
```

Whatever instruction I give it tells me

```
E:\software\node\node.exe E:\software\node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js run dist:windows --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**How can I build the project correctly. It is returning nothing other than 0**

I just updated npm using `npm install -g npm`

Comment: Have you any log available?

Comment: no... till now, i haven't intentionally created, where can i found one?? @Emanuele

Comment: Well usually the exit code 0 means that the script has no errors. By the why are you running this command instead of simply run `yarn dist:windows`?

Comment: i'm not executing that big command, webstrom is : https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL1rf.png @Emanuele

Comment: just to try, move no the package.json directory with cmd and run `yarn dist:windows`

Comment: i tried in the cmd, it doesn't work..

Comment: @Emanuele thanks, i put that command inside webstorm terminal and it works...